# parsed Exception in dao when after saving date

Tags: java, sql, date, jdbc

I am using H2 database and a Date datatype I am working with spring Mvc in   and in my model i am using java.sql.date for my pojo ,i wrote an add new order method that looks like this

```
    public final Order addOrder(Order order) {
        LOGGER.debug("addOrder({})", order);
        MapSqlParameterSource
        namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();

        namedParameters.addValue("petrolQty",
                order.getPetrolQty());

        namedParameters.addValue("price",
                order.getPrice());

        namedParameters.addValue("orderDate",
                order.getOrderDate());

        namedParameters.addValue("truckId",
                order.getTruckId());

        KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate
                .update(addOrderSql,
                        namedParameters, generatedKeyHolder);
        order.setOrderId(generatedKeyHolder.getKey().intValue());
        return order;
    }
```

so i wrote a test which parses but when i debug at the last line i get a java.text.parsedException here is my test and how better can i do the conversion of dates ?

```
private static final String DATE = "2006-1-21";

    @Autowired
    private OrderDao orderDao;

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

 @Test
    public void addOrder() throws ParseException {
        Collection<Order> orders = orderDao.getAllOrders();
        int sizeBefore = orders.size();

        Date dd =  formatter.parse(DATE);
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(dd.getTime());

        Order order = new Order(234.3, 342.2,sqlDate , 1);
        Order order1 = orderDao.addOrder(order);
        Assert.assertNotNull(order1);


    Assert.assertTrue(order.getOrderDate().equals(formatter.parse("2006-1-21")));**excetion thrown here java.text.parsedException during debug only.
            Assert.assertTrue((sizeBefore+1) == orderDao.getAllOrders().size());
```

at thelast line i get the exception during debug but thats after it actually saves to db, also what better way to handle this dates ?thanks
my order class
* order date is java.sql.Date

```
public class Order {
    private Integer orderId;
    private Double petrolQty;
    private Double price;
    private Date orderDate;

    private Integer truckId;
    public Order() {
    }
    public final Integer getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }
```

sql -order.add =

```
INSERT INTO orderz (petrolQty, price, orderDate, truckId) values (:petrolQty,:price, :orderDate, :truckId)
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. And tell us at which line it throws the exception.

Comment: And shows us your `Order` class.

Comment: i will edit the question now @KrzysztofKrasoń

Comment: @KrzysztofKrasoń i have posted it

Comment: Please add the full exception stack trace.
And where is the error, on the last assert, the one that validates the order size?

Comment: @KrzysztofKrasoń i think there are no exceptions my bad after long hours coding i guess , at debug me end it showed the method name and exception that it throws i mistook for an exception, but i still dont know whats the best way for the date conversions can you give me a better solutions for the dates , i was thinking joda but havent used it before

Comment: @valik The *Joda-Tim*e project is now in maintenance mode, with the project advising migration to the *java.time* classes. Search Stack Overflow for many existing Questions on java.time, Instant, ZonedDateTime, OffsetDateTime, LocalDate, and so on. Never use the troublesome old legacy classes such as `Date` and `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`..